# How do I add a gradient (black to grey / top bottom) to an image on hover?

Tags: css

Got close with this, but for some reason it loses the gradient.  I think it has to do with z-index but not sure.  When I put an images file that cannot be found, when you hover then you see the gradient.

```
<style>
.border_overlay:hover {

/* Image Dimensions */
width:160px;
height:160px;

/* Moves overlay over Image */
position:relative;
z-index:1;
margin-bottom:-160px;

/* SVG fallback(Opera 11.10-, IE9) */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjxkZWZzPjxsaW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudCBpZD0iZ3JhZGllbnQiIHgxPSIwJSIgeTE9IjAlIiB4Mj0iMCUiIHkyPSIxMDAlIj48c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjAlIiBzdHlsZT0ic3RvcC1jb2xvcjpyZ2JhKDAsMCwwLDEpOyIgLz48c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMCUiIHN0eWxlPSJzdG9wLWNvbG9yOnJnYmEoMTI4LDEyOCwxMjgsMSk7IiAvPjwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+PC9kZWZzPjxyZWN0IGZpbGw9InVybCgjZ3JhZGllbnQpIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiAvPjwvc3ZnPg==);

/* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(128,128,128,1));

/* Firefox 3.6+ */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(128,128,128,1));

/* Chrome 7+ & Safari 5.03+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(1, rgba(128,128,128,1)));

/* IE5.5 - IE7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#FF000000,EndColorStr=#FF808080);

/* IE8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr=#FF000000,EndColorStr=#FF808080)"

/* Border width and color */
    border:1px solid black;

/* Border Opacity */
opacity:0.3;
.filter:alpha(opacity=30);
-ms-filter: 'alpha (opacity=30)';
}

</style>

<img class="border_overlay" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" width=160 height=160 alt="Image">
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the overlay and the image have to be two different elements. You can't change an images opacity and expect the background of the same element to ignore that property. I'd do it more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qDdVw/

Comment: Sweet that worked out nicely.  Thanks so much!